# Error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

New to python, trying to convert json file to csv and wrote below code but keep getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error. Please suggest.

```
import json
import csv

#x= '''open("Test_JIRA.json","r")'''
#x = json.load(x)

with open('Test_JIRA.json') as jsonfile:
    x = json.load(jsonfile)

f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w"))

# Write CSV Header, If you dont need that, remove this line
f.writerow(["id", "self", "key", "customfield_12608", "customfield_12607"])

for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["id"],
                x["self"],
                x["key"],
                x["fields"]["customfield_12608"],
                x["fields"]["customfield_12607"]
                ])
```

Here is sample 1 row input json file data:

```
{"expand":"schema,names","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":100,"issues":[{"expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields","id":"883568","self":"https://jira.xyz.com/rest/api/2/issue/223568","key":"AI-243","fields":{"customfield_22608":null,"customfield_12637":"2017-10-12T21:46:00.000-0700"}}]}
```

Comment: can you please add the input JSON file and the output error as it is shown in console

Comment: Please provide the complete traceback.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see problem is here

```
for x in x:
```

Note, that `x` in your code is a `dict`, not `list`. I think (based on provided json example) you need something like

```
for x in x['issues']:
```

Also, @Reti43 note in comment, that keys of `dicts` in `x['issues']` vary between elements. To make your code more safe you could use `get`

```
for x in x['issues']:
    f.writerow([x.get("id"),
                x.get("self"),
                x.get("key"),
                x.get("fields", {}).get("customfield_12608"),
                x.get("fields", {}).get("customfield_12607")
                ])
```

Comment: The variable names make no difference, because the loop target is evaluated only once. The `for x in x` fails because it is iterating over the *keys* of the dict (which explains the "string indices must be integers" error). The second part of your answer is what really matters (although `for x in x['issues']` will work just as well).

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for comment, I will correct my answer

Comment: The problem is just as ekhumoro described. However, the code is still in for a nasty surprise when it tries to access the custom field keys, as they seem to vary between issues. Also, just because `for x in x['issues']` will work, it doesn't mean at the end of the loop the last item won't overshadow the object. So it's still advisable to do `for issue in x['issues']`.

Comment: @kvorobiev. I think you can safely assume that the top-level keys will always be there (see the [JIRA Rest API examples](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-query-issues)). So the `get()` would only be needed for the custom fields.

Comment: Thanks @kvorobiev, it works fine now. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @kvorobiev - i can run program successfully at my local machine now. But if i run same program in my linux box, i get error "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded". Is it because my linux box running python 2.7 an d local 3.6